# virsh: Overwrite existing snapshot

Tags: virsh

How can I overwrite an existing snapshot with virsh?

If I try to use an existing name, then I get this error message:

```
> virsh -c qemu+tls://virtserv5/system snapshot-create-as myvm --name snapshot-foo
error: internal error: unexpected domain snapshot snapshot-foo already exists
```

Comment: Please leave a comment instead of down-voting. What is wrong with my question?

Comment: Take a look at how snapshots are explained here - https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/I_created_an_external_snapshot,_but_libvirt_will_not_let_me_delete_or_revert_to_it. It's not possible to do what you want based on how snapshots work.

Comment: @slm your wiki page is from 2016, things changed a bit since then. Guettli, you should probably post what version of virsh, qemu/kvm, linux distribution and as much system information as you can, as that helps to lookup documentation and explain what you can or cant do.

Comment: @Leo - those are the official wiki pages for the libvirt project. The underlying mechanisms for snapshots hasn't changed, it's how they work. Having specific versions would definitely help but regardless, the way snapshots is implemented doesn't allow for overwrites.

Comment: @slm You are right, but it's a wiki nonetheless. I agree with you that there is no simple "overwrite feature" though. I just thought of the rename option, but realized that will keep the old snapshot around, and I don't know if that's what he wants. As there is not enough info on the reasons for the overwrite I guess that's all we can do for tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending on @anon answer to the question and @slm comments.

> How can I overwrite an existing snapshot with virsh?

I can think of two solutions for this question.

1. To delete the old snapshot and "overwrite" it with a new one. Which
   basically means making a new snapshot of the current state. As you are planning on overwriting it anyway I don't see the need or use in keeping the old one, other than to save steps, as stated by Anon. Steps below.
2. To "*rename/clone*" the snapshot.

For the *first option (delete)*, if you are using internal snaps, you could try with:

```
sudo virsh snapshot-delete $VM_ID $SNAPSHOT_NAME
sudo virsh snapshot-create-as $VM_ID $SNAPSHOT_NAME
```

Which, for the record, doesn't seem to far away from a overwrite, you could even do it in a single line using `&&`. Don't know the reason for asking an overwrite (specifying it could help getting better answers or alternatives).

For the *second option (rename)*, you should keep in mind that [the *man page* for virsh warns](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/libvirt-clients/virsh.1.en.html) the following for the setting:

> If --rename is specified, then the edits can change the snapshot name.
>   If --clone is specified, then changing the snapshot name will create a
>   clone of the snapshot metadata. If neither is specified, then the
>   edits must not change the snapshot name. Note that changing a snapshot
>   name must be done with care, since the contents of some snapshots,
>   such as internal snapshots within a single qcow2 file, are accessible
>   only from the original name.

And you could try:

`snapshot-edit domain [snapshotname] [--current] {[--rename] | [--clone]}`

---

If, on the other hand, **you are using external snapshots**, you could also try the `--reuse-external` option for `snapshot-create-as`. Keep in mind the warning about the existing file. I'm not sure it will work as you want without more information on the reasons you have for the feature, so, here is the info from the man page regarding this option:

> If --reuse-external is specified, and the domain XML or diskspec
>   option requests an external snapshot with a destination of an existing
>   file, then the destination must exist and be pre-created with correct
>   format and metadata. The file is then reused; otherwise, a snapshot is
>   refused to avoid losing contents of the existing files.

---

In any case: **I do recommend you clone the VM and play in the copy**, don't try on production systems.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I overwrite an existing snapshot with virsh?

You probably can't.

What you're asking for doesn't match the implementation semantics of VM snapshots. This is because snapshots usually have some sort of parent and a set of things that are different from that of the parent. If you were to replace one snapshot with another what would happen if their parents were different? What if the snapshot you're replacing has changed blocks used in descendant snapshots? These are things that are already handled by combining different operations.

The typical way to achieve what you're describing would be to delete the old snapshot and create a new one which just so happens to have the same name as the one that was deleted.